# Sql procedure slow using 2 dates d1 and d2

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have 2 problems, first when i use 2 defined dates my request works but when i try to do this with two var which came from my C# code it doesnt work it's very slow. And then if i use a limit with those 2 vars it works untill 294 but at 295 it doesnt work i do not know why. There is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prc_get_list_resa(d1 date, d2 date, p_id_resa integer, p_state character, p_id_clt integer, p_id_chauff integer, p_id_conv integer, p_id_fact integer, p_id_org integer)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
      ref refcursor;
    BEGIN
        OPEN ref FOR
          SELECT *
          FROM db_reservations res
          LEFT JOIN db_clients clt ON res.id_clt_resa = clt.id_clt
          LEFT JOIN db_organisations org ON res.id_org_resa = org.id_org
          LEFT JOIN db_chauffeurs chauff ON res.id_chauff_resa = chauff.id_chauff
          LEFT JOIN db_vehicules vehic ON res.id_vehic_resa = vehic.id_vehic
          LEFT JOIN db_type_transport ttransp ON res.id_type_transp_resa = ttransp.id_type_transp

          WHERE  res.date_dep_resa >= (select distinct d1 from db_reservations) and res.date_dep_resa < (select distinct d2 from db_reservations)
           and  ((res.id_resa        = p_id_resa)   or (p_id_resa = 0))
           and  ((res.id_org_resa    = p_id_org)    or (p_id_org = 0))
           and  ((res.id_chauff_resa = p_id_chauff) or (p_id_chauff = 0))
           and  ((res.id_clt_resa    = p_id_clt)    or (p_id_clt  = 0))
           and  ((res.id_conv_resa   = p_id_conv)   or (p_id_conv = 0))
           and  ((res.id_fact_resa   = p_id_fact)   or (p_id_fact = 0))
           and  ((res.etat_resa      = p_state)     or (p_state   = ''))

           order by id_org_resa,id_clt_resa, date_dep_resa,type_trajet asc limit 1000;
      RETURN ref ;
    END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION prc_get_list_resa(date, date, integer, character, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The c# code :

```
public static List<Reservation> ListReservations(string param, int p_id_resa, string p_state, int p_id_clt, int p_id_chauff, int p_id_conv, string p_deb_period, string p_fin_period, int p_id_fact, int p_id_pass, int p_id_org)
{
    string d1, d2;
    DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Today;

    var today = baseDate;
    var yesterday = baseDate.AddDays(-1);
    var thisWeekStart = baseDate.AddDays(-(int)baseDate.DayOfWeek);
    var thisWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
    var lastWeekStart = thisWeekStart.AddDays(-7);
    var lastWeekEnd = thisWeekStart.AddSeconds(-1);
    var thisMonthStart = baseDate.AddDays(1 - baseDate.Day);
    var thisMonthEnd = thisMonthStart.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);
    var lastMonthStart = thisMonthStart.AddMonths(-1);
    var lastMonthEnd = thisMonthStart.AddSeconds(-1);
    if (param == "lastweek")
    {
        d1 = thisWeekStart.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        d2 = thisWeekEnd.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    else if (param == "lastmonth")
    {
        d1 = thisMonthStart.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        d2 = thisMonthEnd.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    else if (param == "today")
    {
        d1 = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        d2 = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }
    else if (param == "all")
    {
        d1 = "01-01-1900";
        d2 = "01-01-2100";
    }
    else
    {
        d1 = p_deb_period;
        d2 = p_fin_period;
    }

    NpgsqlDataReader dr = null;
    List<Reservation> lst_reservation = new List<Reservation>();
    ApplicationConfig db = new ApplicationConfig();
    string cnx = db.getConnectionStringFromXML();
    NpgsqlConnection npgsqlcnx = new NpgsqlConnection(cnx);

    npgsqlcnx.Open();
    NpgsqlTransaction tran = npgsqlcnx.BeginTransaction();
    //  NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("prc_get_reservations", npgsqlcnx);
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("prc_get_list_resa", npgsqlcnx);

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if ((d1 != "") && (d1 != null))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", DateTime.Parse(d1));
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900"));
    }
    if ((d2 != "") && (d2 != null))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", DateTime.Parse(d2));
        }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2100"));
    }


    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_resa", p_id_resa);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_state", p_state);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_clt", p_id_clt);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_chauff", p_id_chauff);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_conv", p_id_conv);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_fact", p_id_fact);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id_org", p_id_org);



    dr = command.ExecuteReader();

    int t = dr.FieldCount;
    lst_reservation = Reservations(dr);
    //    lst_reservation = Reservations(dr);
    npgsqlcnx.Close();
    return lst_reservation;
}
```

Comment: What are 294 and 295 referring to?

Comment: 294 and 295 refers to the limit

Comment: @mjwills i'll edit the post and put the c# code

Comment: When you say it work at 294 and it doesn't at 295, what do you mean by that? What acts differently with a limit of 295 that makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Also include code showing what this means `first when i use 2 defined dates my request works` - so I can compare the working code vs non-working code.

Comment: Also add some comments explaining what this part of the query is trying to do - `(select distinct d1 from db_reservations)`.

Answer (score 1):

d1 and d2 must be declared as DateTime variables - don't store dates in strings. Especially when passing those dates to a database that expects a date rather than a string.

In all likelihood, you are passing a string to the database and the database is interpreting that string differently (e.g. is 1/2/2017 1st Feb or 2nd Jan?). By passing only dates to the database there is no ambiguity.

Thus instead of code like:

```
d1 = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

you will use code like:

```
d1 = DateTime.Today;
```

Also change this line:

```
WHERE  res.date_dep_resa >= (select distinct d1 from db_reservations) and res.date_dep_resa < (select distinct d2 from db_reservations)
```

to:

```
WHERE  res.date_dep_resa >= d1 and res.date_dep_resa < d2
```

Comment: Thank you i'll try this and i'll keep you informed !

Comment: I have the same problem, i changed this as you said but i keep have the problem of slow query. If i change the condition of the query by putting 2 dates like '01-01-1900' and '01-01-2100' it works good and i have my 1600 rows and if i use d1 and d2 it works for limit 294 but limit 295 it doesnt work

Comment: Update your post to show the current code (after changing d1 and d2 to DateTime).